# PowerShell - Remove-ADGroupMember - Locking my admin account

Tags: powershell, active-directory, kerberos, powershell-ise

I have the following line of code in a PowerShell file, intended to remove a user from all Active Directory groups beginning with an @ symbol;

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "@*"' | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $UserID
```

It actually works fine, and successfully removes them from the correct groups, however the script locks my admin account every time it's run. Weird!

From trawling the internet for a while, I suspect it's something to do with it 'using up' my Kerberos authentication tokens (it uses too many, as it runs for every single AD group beginning with @), or it thinks I'm trying to do something malicious because I'm sending such a large amount of commands in a short time?

Is there a way for me to amend this line of code, so that instead of running Remove-ADGroupMember for every single @ group in the Active Directory, it only runs for the groups that the user is a member of? Or any other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | where {$_.name -like "@*"} | select -expandproperty name
foreach($group in $groups){
Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members $user
}
```

It will only looking for the groups that the $user is a member in so you should be fine token wise.

Don't forget to change $user with user name or fill the variable beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't have an AD infrastructure at home, but it looks like your example has nothing defining `$UserID`.

Comment: Hi Burt_harris. $UserID is already defined further back in the script. I can echo it without issue, so the variable is set correctly.